# xts convert data frame to character

Tags: r, xts

I have a csv file and extract data using

```
banknifty <- as.xts(read.zoo("banknifty.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T))
```

`read.zoo()` extracts the data frame with numeric values but as I apply `as.xts()`, the `data. frame`'s numeric values get converted to characters.

```
# banknifty[1,] gives 
2008-01-01 09.34:00 "10" "12" "13"
```

I want `as.xts` should return `data.frame` with numeric values. 
How to avoid this problem?

Comment: `read.zoo` ( internally read.table) should give you numeric values directly. You need to add some lines of your csv file to the question to see why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 7):

You're confused about the nature of xts/zoo objects.  They are matrices with an ordered index attribute, therefore you cannot mix types in xts/zoo objects like you can in a data.frame.

The reason your object is being converted to character is because some of the values in your file are not numeric.  This is also why you get the `NAs introduced by coercion` error when you tried [hd1's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807463/271616) solution.

So the answer to your question is, "fix your CSV file", but we can't help you fix it unless you show us the file's contents.

Comment: I'm confused. xts requires a date variable to be passed, but forces all elements to have the same class. So if I have date and numeric, all ends up being character. If coerce back as numeric with storage.mode, date variable disappears.

Comment: xts is like zoo. You need to pass the data and the dates in separate arguments: `xts(my_matrix, my_dates)`.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem. In my case, the issue was that the as.xts() function tries to convert the date column along with the numeric columns. Because R does not consider dates to be numeric values, it automatically converts the entire data frame to character. I'm assuming that happens in your example as well (you can check this using your .csv-file).

Something like this should help:

```
data.in <- read.csv("banknifty.csv",sep=",",header=T)
data.in[,1] <- format(as.Date(data.in[,1]), format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT", usetz=TRUE) #change tz to whatever applies
data.in[,1] <- as.POSIXct(data.in[,1], "GMT")
data.ts <- xts(data.in[,c(2,3,4,5)], order.by = data.in[,1])
```

(Note that data.ts <- xts(data.in, order.by = data.in[,1]) would replicate the unwanted conversion. Also, apologies that this is probably not the cleanest / most concise code, I'm still learning.)

Answer (score 1):

Use as.numeric and your code will be:

```
> data.in <- as.xts(read.zoo("banknifty.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T);


> sapply(c(1:4), function(n) { data.in[,n] <- as.numeric(data.in[,n]) }, simplify=TRUE )
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
[1,] 6032.25 6040.50 6032.17 6036.29
[2,] 6036.29 6036.29 6020.00 6025.05
[3,] 6025.05 6026.00 6020.10 6023.12
[4,] 6023.12 6034.45 6022.73 6034.45
[5,] 6034.45 6034.45 6030.00 6030.00
[6,] 6030.00 6038.00 6028.25 6038.00
> data.in
                         V2      V3      V4      V5
2007-01-02 10:00:00 6032.25 6040.50 6032.17 6036.29
2007-01-02 10:05:00 6036.29 6036.29 6020.00 6025.05
2007-01-02 10:10:00 6025.05 6026.00 6020.10 6023.12
2007-01-02 10:15:00 6023.12 6034.45 6022.73 6034.45
2007-01-02 10:20:00 6034.45 6034.45 6030.00 6030.00
2007-01-02 10:25:00 6030.00 6038.00 6028.25 6038.00
>
```

Comment: It gives me error:                                                                                                                                           `Error in lapply(c(1:ncol(banknifty)), function(column) { : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.double.xts(banknifty[, column]) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as.double.xts(banknifty[, column]) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In as.double.xts(banknifty[, column]) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In as.double.xts(banknifty[, column]) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: instead of 1:ncol(banknifty), specify only those columns that you want converted.

Comment: I change 1:ncol() to c(1:4) but still does not work. Gives me the same error as above

Comment: Next time, please use [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.org), as requested, but see the edited answer.

Comment: >  sapply(c(1:4), function(n) { data.in[,n] <- as.numeric(data.in[,n]) }, simplify=TRUE )   This command does not make an y change to data.in. It returns the data in same format with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
> sapply(c(1:4), function(n) { data.in[,n] <- as.numeric(data.in[,n]) }, simplify=TRUE )
```

This command does not make any change to data.in. It returns the data in same format with quotes

```
> data.in
                         V2      V3      V4      V5
2007-01-02 10:00:00 "6032.25" "6040.50" "6032.17" "6036.29"
2007-01-02 10:05:00 "6036.29" "6036.29" "6020.00" "6025.05"
2007-01-02 10:10:00 "6025.05" "6026.00" "6020.10" "6023.12"
```